# Is there a way to write Bootstrap class attribute into a CSS file or is there anyway to get around for it to work?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, spacing

My question comes from this situation:

I'm now using Twitter Bootstrap 4 Beta to define spacing for some divs, like

```
<div class="ml-0 px-0">
```

However, as I design my page further I found myself use this div repetitively, so I think it would be better to give this div a class and write the same spacing rule in a CSS file.

I checked out [the BT4 official page about spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/) and the number(size) defined in its spacing rule means

> 0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to 0
>
> 1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
>
> 2 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .5

But I found it difficult to understand $spacer so it would be hard for me to transform the number into pixels or whatever.

So is there any way possible way to combine this BT feature with a custom CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using Bootstrap 4 *beta* and not the actual version?!

Comment: I just learned Bootstrap 4 beta from a Udemy tutorial several days ago so I am still kinda trying it out and then will jump to the actual version :) Does the actual version have any way that could solve this problem?

Comment: `$spacer` is likely a Sass variable

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/#sass-options

Comment: Thanks cricket_007 and Vandesh so it is 1 rem by default 